# Make pandoc link whole citation instead of only the year

Tags: pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I use pandoc-style Markdown with `pandoc-citeproc` and citations that look like this:

```
... research and progress [@murray2008open; @piwowar2013data] blah blah ...
```

The result works, but the links this creates in the text only links the year, not the whole citation.  I.e., the text looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to make the whole citation a link, not just the year.  I can't find an option for pandoc-citeproc that controls this behavior, and after spending some time looking at CSL, I have not yet found how that could control it either.  I'm using `acm-siggraph.csl`.

How can I make entire citations be links, instead of only the year portion of the citation?  If this is controlled by the CSL, could someone tell me the relevant elements or constructs that affect th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this issue on the pandoc-citeproc tracker: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/issues/268

Comment: Ahhhh.... I see the problem now. That's unfortunate, but now I understand the current behavior and why it has to stay this way. Thanks!